# The discriminant of a specific type of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

I am currently considering a family of polynomials in $t$, defined as follows: $$P_n(t)=nt^{2n-1}-nyt^{n-1}+t-x$$Here, $x$ and $y$ are constants. It is of interest when this polynomial has a multiple root - when its discriminant is equal to zero. For $P_2(t)$, the expression is $2(2y-1)^3-27x^2$, and for $P_3(t)$, the expression is the more complicated $8748xy^5-729y^4+20250x^2y^2-4800xy+9375x^4+256$.

I am now stuck; I cannot find an expression for $P_4(t)=4t^7-4yt^3+t-x$, or one in general. Is there  a simple form? Also, does anyone happen to be able to find an expression for $P_4$? If that can't be done, is it possible to know the highest degree of $y$ that will be found in this discriminant expression?

Thanks a lot - any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5B4*t%5E7-4*y*t%5E3%2Bt-x%2Ct%5D) returns $$-4096 (823543 x^6 + 3226944 x^4 y^2 - 1769472 x^2 y^7 + 1505280 x^2 y^4\\ - 444528 x^2 y + 65536 y^6 - 55296 y^3 + 11664)$$

Comment: Thanks for this, and showing me the tool of discriminant in Wolfram Alpha.